# How to make transition animation without changing UIViews

Tags: iphone, pdf, animation, transition

I am using pdfReader from here: https://github.com/vfr/Reader to show pdfs.
It is basically a view that you can put inside your other views and displays pdfs. When you flip a page it actually doesn't change a view, so i don't know to make a animation transitions. 
I need to make simple animation when you change a page (like show page coming from the left, right ...). Is there anything i can do eventhough i don't show new views when changing page?
Currently i have this pdfReader view inside scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are giving animation, send your view as a parameter so it will display same view again with animation.